# Ошибка в класса

Tags: python, ооп

после выполнения кода получаю ошибку

```
batch = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
BATCH_FOLDER = 'home/test'

class test:
    def __init__(self, **params):
        if len(batch) > 5:
            BATCH_FOLDER = 'home'
        print(BATCH_FOLDER)


t1 = test()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Без if, это работает подскажите в чем дело? Кажется не логичным влияние условия( которое даже не сработало на выполнение)

По решению это проблемы можно прописать global, но мне интереснее почему это происходит

Кажется, что если есть условие с присвоением, то переменная становится локал, можно ли присваивать так, что бы этого не происходило.

Comment: Ну да, именно так - пока переменная только читается, она считается глобальной, как только есть присваивание - она считается локальной.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо или так:

```
batch = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
BATCH_FOLDER = 'home/test'

class test:
    def __init__(self, **params):
        global BATCH_FOLDER
        if len(batch) > 5:
            BATCH_FOLDER = 'home'
        print(BATCH_FOLDER)


t1 = test()
```

или так:

```
batch = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
BATCH_FOLDER = 'home/test'

class test:
    def __init__(self, **params):
        BATCH_FOLDER = ''
        if len(batch) > 5:
            BATCH_FOLDER = 'home'
        print(BATCH_FOLDER)


t1 = test()
```

вы уж определитесь - в конструкторе `BATCH_FOLDER` - это глобальная или локальная переменная

в вашем коде как только вы выполняете присваивание в переменную `BATCH_FOLDER` Питон понимает, что переменная будет локальной, но присваивание у вас происходит не каждый раз, а только в зависимости от выполнения условия, а затем вы выводите значение переменной `BATCH_FOLDER` (уже каждый раз)

поэтому получается, что переменная то глобальная, то локальная, и Питон от этого офигевает и выдает ошибку

судя по коду вы хотите работать именно с внешней (глобальной) переменной, поэтому в функции `__init__` питону надо бы указать, что переменная `BATCH_FOLDER` - внешняя